# Salesforce to Mule Soft

Tags: salesforce, mule-studio

I have a requirement like, need to pass the Account and contact information from Salesforce to Mule Soft.
It needs to be done by SOAP (WSDL File).

How to get WSDL file from Mulesoft? Anyone have done this is salesforce?
Please guide me how to do this one?

Answer (score 0):

Using Mule Anypoint Studio you can use the Salesforce Connector and a Salesforce flow element that will get Contact information from Salesforce.  The Salesforce Connector in Mule uses the SOAP interface from Salesforce.

Inside your Mule Flow you can simply use

```
<sfdc:query config-ref="SalesforceConfig" query="dsql:SELECT * FROM Contact" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
```

The above code will return you a streaming object.  One of the best things to do at that point is implement a Java transformer afterwards to soak up the results and turn it to whatever you want.

```
<custom-transformer class="org.stackoverflow.transformers.QueryResultsToWhatever" doc:name="Java"/>
```

The class would then be written in java:

```
public class QueryResultsToWhatever extends AbstractMessageTransformer {
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
        throws TransformerException {

    // get the Streaming list of maps that is the payload
    org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator<Map<Object, Object>> CI = message
            .getPayload(org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator.class);

    if (CI.hasNext()) {
        Object _obj = CI.next();
        //Each Iterator represents a row returned from the query
        if (_obj instanceof Map) {

            Map<Object, Object> sfmap = (Map<Object, Object>) _obj;
            // cast it
            // Now you have a Map to access each field inside each row
```

Since this is a pretty simple use case for the Salesforce connector, the tutorials available on https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Salesforce+Connector
Can help greatly.